# After upgrade to Magento 1.9.3.4 admin send email error

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

We have upgraded Magento to 1.9.3.4. When send email from sales order we are getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAllItems() on string in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml:39

Can you please help us on this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting order id in this file ?

Comment: yes Iam getting order ID in this file and the 39 line is foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item):

Comment: Does it happen with all orders or a specific product on an order?